curl fails while curl --compressed works
I have an Ubuntu 24 VM, and from there I'm trying to download a file from a software dist mirror. If I try something like
curl 'http://mirror1/path/to/file.txt --output file.txt

That will fail with curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
Same thing if I try mirror2, mirror3, etc.
If I try the same thing with --compressed added, then it works.
On top of this, another VM on the same machine, an RHEL OS, works just fine without the --compressed tag.
I'm trying to figure out what is so special about this VM that is requiring it to need the compressed tag.
And the real issue is that I'm not able to download software updates using apt-get or pacman or any other package manager I have installed. They all fail to update for some connection error, which I think is the same issue the curl cmd is running into.
